# Where are David & Miranda when the capsule crashes into the ISS?

Tags: plot-explanation, life

In *Life* (2017), David is looking through the window when the capsule destroys the ISS.

[image]

So he sees the destroyed ISS floating in space.

[image]

From where exactly is he seeing the ISS?  He should actually be on the ISS, but here the movie is showing that he & Miranda aren't on the ISS. Then where are they?

The movie doesn't have an IMDB synopsis, so I read its plot on Wikipedia:

> The crew tries to save Sho, but the encounter causes a docking breach
>   that results in the capsule detaching and crashing into the ISS. David
>   and Miranda, the only survivors, realize that the incident has again
>   caused them to enter a decaying orbit. **Aware that Calvin could survive
>   re-entry, David recalls two escape pods, planning to lure Calvin into
>   one pod and pilot it into deep space, allowing Miranda to escape to
>   Earth in the other pod.**

The scene happens exactly here. They also decide to go to the escape pods; what is the exact location where this decision making scene happens?

Miranda starts to shake because the surrounding temperature drops, and she also says "It's **so cold**" to David in this location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are still on the ISS.  The second image is an external view of the ISS as though from the point of view of (the movie equivalent of) an omniscient narrator; it is not what David sees.  Presumably, the filmmakers chose to show the ISS from this angle because it gave a clearer or more complete view than what David was seeing.